# Do the terms of a divergent series eventually always become bigger than those of a convergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof

If $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ are decreasing, non-negative sequences of real numbers and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ diverges, then is it always the case that there exists some positive integer $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $b_n \geq a_n$?

I was originally trying to prove that this result is true as a lemma to prove that if $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ was positive and decreasing and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges that $\lim_{n \to \infty} na_n=0$.

I originally wanted to prove the first statement as the second statement follows after taking $b_n = {1\over{n\ln(n)}}$. I have since realized that there is another solution to the original question which doesn't involve this lemma, but I still am curious to know whether the lemma is true.

I have figured out that the lemma is not true if you take away the requirement that both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are decreasing, but I believe with this restriction, the result should be true.

Comment: To build a counterexample...let $b_n=a_1$ for enough terms, say $N$,  to sum over $1$.  Then let $b_n$ be $a_{N+1}-\epsilon$ for enough terms to sum over $1$, and so on.  Easy to modify this to be strictly decreasing if you prefer.

Comment: You can guarantee that there is an $N$ such that there are always *some* $m$ such that $b_m\geq a_m$, (in fact it is easy to see there must be infinitely many) but you cannot guarantee that $b_m\geq a_m$ for **all** $m>N$.

Answer (score 5):

As discussed in the comments:

To build a counterexample, start with your favorite convergent series $\sum a_n$.  Now, let $b_n=a_1$ for enough terms to sum over $1$.  (you can let $b_k=a_1-\epsilon+\epsilon \times 10^{-k!}$ if you want something strictly decreasing).  Say that takes $N$ terms.  Now let $b_n=a_{N+1}-\epsilon$ for enough terms to sum over $1$ (similar note).  And repeat.

As you see, the idea is to let $b_n$ decrease but only in relative big gaps, presumably very , very far apart.